# DataSnap and create dynamic SQLConnection

Tags: delphi, runtime, database-connection, datasnap

I am creating my fisrt **DataSnap** project. My DSserver (service app)  has this structure:

```
TService : service body - contain DSServer,DSHTTPservice and DSAuthorizeManager.
TDataModule : classes module - containt TDSServerClasses
```

AND

```
TDSServerModule : first serverMethods module - contain TSQLQuery and TDataSetProvider
TDataModule : DB connection module - contain only one SQLConnection now. 
DB connection module not created on start APP!!!
```

So i need dynamicly create "**DB connection module**" and on call "**first serverMethods module**" bind **TSQLQuery** from "**first serverMethods module**" on **TSQLconnection** from "**DB connection module**". But client on open dataset (call server method ) throw `error message: "TSQLconnection property is required"`.

Please , how to do bind TSQLconnection to TSQLQuery runtime ?